# Search and copy and paste of two datasheet according to column python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, jupyter-notebook

first excel sheet

```
    A   C   D   id
0   foo 10  9   1
1   bar 10  8   2
2   foo 10  7   3
3   bar 30  6   4
4   foo 50  5   5
5   bar 60  4   6
6   fo 50  3   7
7   fool 8   2   8
```

second excel sheet

```
0 records   
1          record1 record2  
2     id       A      C   
3      1      
4      6         
5      7      
6      8
```

Now, By matching the (searching) id (id==id) we have to copy the columns A and C and paste A and C into the second excel sheet but the column is mismatched and unnamed

result

```
0  records
1          record1 record2  
2     id       A     C   
3     1       foo    10   
4     6       bar    60   
5     7       fo     50
6     8       fool   8
```

Now, By matching the (searching) id (id==id) we have to copy the columns A and C and paste A and C into the second excel sheet but the column is mismatched and unnamed

result

```
0  records
1          record1 record2  
2     id       A     C   
3     1       foo    10   
4     6       bar    60   
5     7       fo     50
6     8       fool   8
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `pandas.merge` (https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html), as follows:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar', 'fo', 'fool'],
    'C': [10, 10, 10, 30, 50, 60, 50, 8],
    'D': [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2],
    'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
})
print(df1)
"""
      A   C  D  id
0   foo  10  9   1
1   bar  10  8   2
2   foo  10  7   3
3   bar  30  6   4
4   foo  50  5   5
5   bar  60  4   6
6    fo  50  3   7
7  fool   8  2   8
"""
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [1, 6, 7, 8],
    'A': [np.NAN, np.NAN, np.NAN, np.NAN],
    'C': [np.NAN, np.NAN, np.NAN, np.NAN]
})
print(df2)
"""
   id   A   C
0   1 NaN NaN
1   6 NaN NaN
2   7 NaN NaN
3   8 NaN NaN
"""
df3 = pd.merge(df1[['id', 'A', 'C']], df2['id'], how='inner', on='id')
print(df3)
"""
   id     A   C
0   1   foo  10
1   6   bar  60
2   7    fo  50
3   8  fool   8
"""
```

Comment: I changed the question and result can you help how to do it?